# Fazer uma negação em uma codição IF

Tags: java, if

Possuo a seguinte condição `IF`:

```
(ClientesBDM.getNomeEmpresa().toString().equals(ClientesBD.get(1).toString()))
```

Como posso verificar se as variáveis são diferentes, ou seja negar essa condição nesse mesmo `IF`

Comment: Você quer inverter a condição do equals, é isso?

Comment: Conhece o operador de negação lógica? O operador `!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se o objetivo é inverter a condição, basta utilizar o operador de negação no começo:

```
if(!ClientesBDM.getNomeEmpresa().toString().equals(ClientesBD.get(1).toString())) {
  //faça algo caso sejam diferentes

}
```

Porém, se você precisa fazer alguma ação em ambas as situações(seja a igualdade dos objetos verdadeira ou falsa), nunca é demais lembrar que se deve usar `if...else`, evitando cadeias de ifs com condições inversas entre si:

```
if(ClientesBDM.getNomeEmpresa().toString().equals(ClientesBD.get(1).toString())) {
      //faça algo caso sejam iguais

} else {
  //faça algo se forem diferentes
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente negar a minha condição que eu precisava, assim que liberar eu já marco como aceita a pergunta